# Android Spinner radio missing

Tags: android, spinner

I have created one layout with Spinner. I want to show Spinner with radio buttons.

```
Spinner  Spinner_gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_gender);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_gender,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner_gender.setAdapter(adapter);
```

is there any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` uses a `CheckedTextView`. If you absolutely want a `RadioButton`, you should provide your own layout that contains a `RadioButton`.